# How to get message from GCM message body in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which server sends some push notification using GCM server, The implementation is done on both side but i am facing problem is that i can't get notification from message body, it is always showing me "null". But i can see message in messag body using debug.

```
 String message = bundle.getString("message");
    Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived::" + message);
    Log.e(TAG, "from::" + from);
```

and message body is :-

```
Bundle[{google.sent_time=1497866966996, google.message_id=0:1497866967011288%466cbbd8466cbbd8, notification=Bundle[{priority=high, body=Your wallet has been credited with 1.000 point(s)., title=Wallet credited}], collapse_key=com.s.baty}]
```

Comment: You have to send your notification as JSON. Your body should contain content like this {"gcm.notification.title":"",
    "gcm.notification.body":""}   and you can get the body like this bundle.getString("gcm.notification.body")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ,

```
Bundle notificationData = bundle.getBundle("notification");
String body = notificationData.getString("body");
```

Answer (score 0):

It received correct data only

```
   String bodymessage = bundle.getString("body");
```

Problem is print message after converting Sting

```
 Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived::" + message.toString());
```

Comment: use same bundle.getString

Answer (score 0):

You can receive message in onMessage() function of GCMIntentService implementing class. I have created a function for getting proper message and key.

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
     dumpIntent(intent);
}


public void dumpIntent(Intent i) {

        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
            Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String key = it.next();
                Log.e("Intent Data", "[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key) + "]");
            }

        }
    }
```

After that you will easily set message with NotificationManager.