# open url in device's browser without direct to App when click firebase's notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

when click firebase's notification open app.
is there a way open url in device's browser without open app and directly open url in browser when click notification ?

Comment: Buddy, for that you have to set URL into PendingIntent, so that will directly jump to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you know that [how to get message body from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627830/how-to-get-message-from-gcm-message-body-in-android) Just try this  where you open activity on notification click, use this

`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));`

or

call this method in your `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` and get your url from notification and pass `url` in method param.

```
private void sendNotification(String url) {
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,browserIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notification =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(body)
                            .setBigContentTitle(title))
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
}
```

Hope it helps.